# How to monitor the mouse by using iText in PDF in Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to draw a rectangle in Adobe Reader by using mouse click, so I must draw two points of the rectangle.

How can I monitor the mouse to get two points to draw a rectangle in JAVA using iText? Who can help me?

Comment: No one can help you. Once your PDF has been created by iText, iText is no longer involved. The PDF in Adobe Reader doesn't "communicate" in any way with the software you wrote to create the PDF. Hence you can't *monitor* the mouse movements *in Java* no matter which PDF producer you are using. The closest you can get, is to allow end users to draw annotations, have them save the document with those annotations, and extract the location of those annotations using IText afterwards (after they shared the saved PDF with you, e.g. by uploading it to a server).

Comment: So could you tell me how to get the location of those annotations using itext in JAVA?

Comment: That's another question. Also: are you using iText 5 (the old version) or iText 7 (the new, recommended version)? The code is quite different, since iText 7 is a complete rewrite of the old library.

Comment: iText 5?Because I want to sign the PDF and put the sign picture in a rectangle and I want to set the location of the rectangle by my mouse.

Comment: do you have some ideas?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that cosmetic surgery. For the validity of the document, and its signature, it doesn't really matter if there is a visible signature. As long as there is a signed hash.

Comment: Yes,you are right. But in my case, I must make  a visible signature, do yo have some ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eebjsqbj44) to see how others have done this in a cloud context. Are you working on a web application? In that case, go back to your drawing board, because your architecture is seriously flawed (and you'd better not reinvent the wheel, but use an existing service). Are you working on a desktop application? You'll need two apps, Adobe Reader and your custom app, to play together. That's not user-friendly, is it? You should cut your losses and give up. I don't think this is something you can do given your current expertise.

Comment: Yes,In my opinion, firstly I open the adobe reader then select a rectangle by mouse then give the parameter of the rectangle(the location etc.) to my java code,at last use my code to sign the pdf.

Comment: Adobe Reader can sign signature fields already. Is the issue that you don't want to have to predefine the area where the signature gets placed in the PDF?